# It needs some thinking but solvable and nice

Tags: mathematics, geometry, visual

Replace the question mark with your solution

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That was easy!

The figures are n-cubes with half the size of the larger one. The numbers show in which half the little cube is in each coordinate:

```
2 1   -> high x, low  y -> top right
2 2   -> high x, high y -> bottom right
1 2 2 -> low  x, high y, high z -> back's bottom left
```

The next one is the tesseract, which can be divided in 16 half-sided cubes.

The one we want is at the top right, back and far side in the w-dimension:

[image: Incredibly counterproductive]

See? If I measured my time answering this question, it would be like this:

> **3%**......Thinking about the puzzle
>   **97%**.....Trying to draw tesseracts with correct face occlusion on PAINT.

I'm surprised no one took a more practical approach in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

> That would be a hypercube, looking something like
>   [image]